# Redux Thunk : Actions must be plain objects

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-thunk

I followed these [two](https://medium.com/react-native-training/redux-4-ways-95a130da0cdc) [guides](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/291) to implement an API call in an Action with Redux Thunk:

`configureStore.js`

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import rootReducer from '../core/reducers'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

export default function configureStore() {
    let store = createStore(
        rootReducer,
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    );

    return store
}
```

My action, `product.js` :

```
function increment() {
    return {
        type: FETCHING_DATA
    };
}

export function fetchData() {
    return dispatch => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            // Yay! Can invoke sync or async actions with `dispatch`
            dispatch(increment());
        }, 1000);
    };
}
```

And the call from the `Product.js` screen :

```
class Product extends Component {

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {products: null};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchData();
    };

    // Other code
}

function mapStateToProps (state) {
    return {
        cart: state.cart,
        product: state.product
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
    return {
        plusOneProduct: (id) => dispatch(plusOneProduct(id)),
        clearCart: () => dispatch(clearCart()),
        fetchData: () => dispatch(fetchData())
    }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Product);
```

And the main `app.js` file :

```
import {View} from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import {NativeRouter, Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-native';

import {Root} from './config/router';
import configureStore from './configureStore'

const store = configureStore();

const MyApp = () => {
    return (
        <Root store={store}/>
    );
};

export default MyApp;
```

I did follow exactly what the two post were saying and the official documentation, but I have this error when landing in the product page :

> Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

It seems like my React Thunk middleware is not applying. How can I check this ?

Comment: I suspect it has to do with configureStore function. How do you create/declare the store?

Comment: @D-reaper I edited my post

Comment: what is in Root? I am assuming Provider is there? Maybe try to move Provider so that it is now in app.js and pass the store from there?

Comment: @D-reaper I don't have a Provider in root. Root is a StackNavigator. Is provider needed in order to make this works ?

Comment: @D-reaper That was it ! I missed the step were Provider was one of the most important thing in Redux. Can you please create an answer so I could accept it ?

Comment: I've added my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments section, the problem is that you have forgotten to put the Provider component to wrap your top level component. So to fix this issue, you should wrap your Root with Provider component and pass the store there.

```
//... rest of imports
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const store = configureStore();

const MyApp = () => {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Root/>
      </Provider>
    );
};
```